# Confusion in interpreting why $A\subseteq B$ implies $A\cap X\subseteq B\cap X$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm working on the beginnings of Set Theory and I need help understand the proof the question below:

> Prove that $A ⊆ B$ and $A \cap B^\complement=\emptyset$ are equivalent.

The proof is:

> $$ A⊆ B\implies A∩ B^\complement ⊆ B ∩ B^\complement$$
> As $B ∩ B^\complement = \emptyset$,
> $$A ∩ B^\complement \subseteq \emptyset$$
> $$A ∩ B^\complement = \emptyset$$

Therefore, both statements are equivalent.

My confusion lies in the step $A∩ B^\complement ⊆ B ∩ B^\complement$. What is the logic for this? How can we "add" the intersection of $B^\complement$ to each side of the subset?

Comment: Did you mean, "Prove that...and $A\cap B^C\color{red}{=\emptyset}\,"?$

Comment: You can "add" anything to intersections of subsets.  If every element of $A$ is in $B$.  Then every element that is in both $A$ and $X$ is in both $B$ and in $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, say you have sets $A,B,C$ such that $A \subseteq B$. Then $A \cap C \subseteq B \cap C$. This is because if for arbitrary $x$, $x \in A \cap C$, $x \in C$ and $x \in A \subseteq B$, so $x \in B$ too. Hence $x \in B \cap C$.

Answer (score 0):

If every element of $A$ is in $B$.  Then every element that is in both $A$ and $X$ is in both $B$ and in $X$.

==========

It's direct  from definitions.

$A \subseteq B$ means for all $x$, if $x \in A$ then $x \in B$.

And for all $x$, if $x \in M\cap N$ then $x \in M$ and $x \in N$.

So if $A\subseteq B$ then.....

If $x \in A \cap X$ then $x \in A$ and $x\in X$.  And since $A\subseteq B$ and $x \in A$ we know $x \in B$.  And as $x\in X$ then $x \in B$ and $x \in X$.  So $x \in B\cap X$.

So if $x \in A\cap X$ then $x \in B\cap X$.  And that, by definition means $A\cap X \subset B\cap X$.

So $A\subseteq B \implies A\cap X \subseteq B\cap X$.